# Javascript Canvas Optimization

Tags: javascript, optimization, canvas

Here's a js fiddle to what I'm attempting:

http://jsfiddle.net/bnjhhoze/

Everything important happens in

```
render()
```

The canvas incorporates the mouse's location into its color calculations for each block for each frame. Now no matter what I seem to cut out of the function, the canvas renders around 10fps at large size (1600 x 900).

Even when it's just rendering purely black, no fill style changes, it renders at 10fps.

Any insight into what could be causing this?

Comment: Way too much code man.. And you're supposed to post code in the question, not on jsfiddle

Comment: @Izzey Sorry for the overwhelming amount of code, I'm not really sure how to distill it without oversimplifying it to a point of not being helpful. Would a brief word explanation of what happens assist those in the future?

Comment: Have you tried using the profiler in Chrome?

Comment: Well. A the bigger the canvas the more blocks there are, and the blocks are updated quickly. Having `setTimeout` and `requestAniamtionFrame` at the same time also can have something to do with it. And just because it's black doesn't means it's not updating, you can draw black on black.

Comment: @BrantOlsen I have, but I'm afraid I'm not quite at the level of expertise to understand exactly what I'm looking at.

In the timeline, the longest running items are my script in the animation frame. When I ran a CPU Profile I saw that set fillstyle takes up a majority of the time, but that seems to make sense to me, as its run for every block, every frame.

Comment: Then don't set the fill style for every block. If you can batch blocks that have the same fill style and draw them at the same time, you don't have to change your context's state so much. This is a common optimization in game engines, it's just a little counter intuitive to how you might do it logically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is a bit too broad to answer. It could be anything from a small one-line inefficiency, your whole approach may need to be reworked, or you really are just pushing too many pixels.

So rather than giving you a fish, you should learn to fish yourself.

[Here are docs on the javascript profiling tools built into Chrome.](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling) That will tell you how to identify bottlenecks in your code and iron them out.

---

One thing you should know though, is that 2D canvas is slow. It's very fill rate dependent. Which means the more pixels you paint, the slower it is. And the nature of your code is that it paints a lot of pixels.

If you could use WebGL, you could achieve some amazing framerates through hardware acceleration. But that requires completely re-architecting everything about this and learning GLSL. [See examples here](http://glslsandbox.com/). It's amazing what you can do with GLSL.

Comment: Thank you, I was curious if Web GL would circumvent the issues I'm having. I'll be sure to look more in-depth into the profiling tools. I'll also take a dive into GLSL this weekend, something I've been avoiding for too long haha.

Comment: If you find the bottle neck is not in your own code, but something the browser is doing, then you need to figure out how to do that thing less. Or completely rethink your approach :) GLSL is fun, if you want to go that road.

Comment: @RyanKilleen May I recommend https://www.shadertoy.com/ as a first approach? It was my first successful attempt at using WebGL.

Comment: @AlexWayne. Agreed that WebGL is much faster & more efficient at operations like Shaders and Blending Filters.  But modern browsers also hardware accelerate 2D Canvas, and, if the device has one, the GPU renders 2D drawings very efficiently--perhaps more efficiently then 3D because 2D is "flatter" than 3D (pun intended!) and 2D naturally lends itself to the GPU's methods of drawing through compositing. So be sure to test 2D canvas also...depending on your design requirements. ;-)